# How can I access to an internal static class from another assembly?

Tags: c#

I've the following situation:

1) I have an internal static class where my software initialize a form
2) I would like to get the instance of this form to use for other reasons.

Example of code:

Class1:

```
 namespace x {
       internal static class Program {
         private static Form mainx;
         private static void Main() {
           .....
           .....
           mainx=new Form(.....);
           Application.run(mainx);
         }
       }
    }
```

Class2:
I want to use one thing like this:

```
Form1 try=Program.mainx;
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 4):

If both assemblies are signed, you can use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to expose internal members of an assembly to another.

I often use this to enable unit testing of internal classes without having to expose them as public.

Answer (score 3):

You could mark the assembly with the internal class as a friend assembly on the other assembly, with the attribute [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You will find more informations about this on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx).

You need to add this line to your `AssemblyInfo` class (in the `Properties` folder), i.e. on the last line. This must be added in the project where you have declared the internal class.

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("NameOfOtherAssembly")]
```

If you with to retrieve the `mainx` property of your `Program` class, you need to make a visible (public or internal) getter on your class:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static Form mainx;

    ...

    public static Form GetForm()
    {
        return mainx;
    }
}
```

In your second class, you should then be able to get the form by calling `GetForm()`:

```
Form1 try=Program.GetForm();
```

Comment: Can you show a full example? I added [assembly tag] but I can't access to the property mainx

Comment: @SanginetoS. I've added a little example.

Comment: I had yet add it. But what i have to write in the second class to call my property?

Comment: You need to reference this assembly and just call the method. Exactly the same as the method would be public.

Comment: @SanginetoS. Sorry, I didn't realize that your `mainx` property is private. The method with `InternalsVisibleTo` works only for internal properties, not for private. Edited my answer again :)